# Получить значение inputa

Tags: jquery

Есть такая верстка

```
<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Получить консультацию
                            <input class="ttt" value="Получить консультацию" type="hidden"/>
                            </a>

<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Получить консультацию1
                            <input class="ttt" value="Получить консультацию" type="hidden"/>
                            </a>

<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Получить консультацию2
                            <input class="ttt" value="Получить консультацию" type="hidden"/>
                            </a>
```

Как посредством Jquery получить значение рядом стоящего input при на жатии на a.order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы говорите про вложенный инпут то:

```
$('.order')
  .click(function(e){
     var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
     var $input = $a.find('input');
     var value = $input.val();
  });
```

Comment: Зачем `$(e.currentTarget)`? Можно просто `$(this)`.

Comment: Можно много какими способами, я привык добывать значения через ивентовый обьект, можно сказать даже, не сильно доверяю this'у :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.order').on('click', function(){
       alert($(this).data("value"));
   });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-value="Получить консультацию">Получить консультацию</a>

<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-value="Получить консультацию1">Получить консультацию1</a>

<a class="order" style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-value="Получить консультацию2">Получить консультацию2</a>
```